# jquery plugins: Tooltip plugin using live()

Tags: jquery-plugins, tooltip, hover, live, onmousemove

I need a tooltip plugin that depends on live() method instead of normal hoever and mousemove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just created my own plugin instead
[monnaTip](http://gadelkareem.com/2010/02/25/jquery-plugin-monnatip/)